# Stretch table coming from Excel to PowerPoint in C#

Tags: c#, html, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to stretch a table in PowerPoint via C#

The table has been copied from Excel into PowerPoint, the issue is that when pasting the table content is really small and can't be read.

What I'm doing basically is, copying a HTML file into the

```
Clipboard.SetText(html);
```

Pasting it into an Excel range

```
sheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial();  
sheet.Columns.AutoFit();
sheet.Rows.AutoFit();
sheet.UsedRange.Copy(Missing.Value);
```

Now, I want to paste it in correct place in PowerPoint

```
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide slide in presentation.Slides)
{
     foreach (PowerPoint.Shape pptshape in slide.Shapes)
     {
           if (!pptshape.Type.ToString().Equals("msoAutoShape") && pptshape.AlternativeText.Contains("|"))
           {
               if (xlsSheetName == pptSheetName && xlsShapeName == pptxlsShapeName)
               {
                   ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial();
               }
           }
     }
}
```

It copies my table in PowerPoint at the place I choose.

But the issue is, the table is really thiny and small and illisible, because it's too small.

Is there a stretch function in C# for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also:

1. select all the cells you need in Excel
2. copy them in the Clipboard
3. paste it in powerpoint
4. resize the shape table

   var clipbordCache = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

   //copy in excel...

   //paste in powerpoint

   var table = slide.shapes.Paste();
   Clipboard.SetDataObject(clipbordCache);

   //resize

   table.Width = 200;

Comment: Oh, you are right - I assumed that he already does that, sorry!
But even thhis table is quite ugly :/
Also, it deletes the clipboard, which I really do hate from a user experience standpoint.

Comment: no wait, the clipboard is restored using Clipboard.SetDataObject(clipbordCache); when the table is ugly you can format it resizing and/or applying default powerpoint styles...

Comment: look there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh273476(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: how do you copy in Excel? do you have something like Cells.Copy() ??

Comment: this is the way to copy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876918/copy-cells-in-excel-using-c-sharp   and then you should have data in clipboard

Comment: `var table = slide.Shapes.Paste();` cannot work, you try to assign to a variable a procedure which actually doesn't return a value. That's the issue.

Comment: it doesn't return a value if there are no data to paste. Could you poste the code?

Comment: this post is pretty similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228883/copying-a-range-of-cells-from-excel-into-powerpoint-using-vsto   they do app.ActiveWindow.View.Paste();  instead of slide.Shapes.Paste()

Comment: I know that ... You aren't replying to my question. It works the way I do it. But the pasted table doesn't stretch and that's my issue......

Comment: ok. that's probably because the original input in Excel is from HTML so you have to use .PasteSpecial() in PowerPoint also. I was assuming that copying in Excel would give you real excel content instead of HTML content.

Comment: If I paste in Excel, it paste correctly, then I copy the Excel table, which isn't HTML. And paste it in PowerPoint, everything works, you still didn't reply on the original question, but you were giving me a solution that I already posted. The question was, how to stretch my table in PowerPoint, means, it already exists.

Comment: you have to set .Width an .Height like a normal shape. Check also the prop. .TextFrame.AutoSize, when it set to PpAutoSize.ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText the shape doesn't resize. In that case you can change it to PpAutoSize.ppAutoSizeNone or make the font size bigger together with resizing width and height

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing in the past - If I recall correctly, you have to set the width /height property of the new table object to something bigger (something depends on the layout of your sheet)
But Powerpoint might ignore that, if the text is too small - in that case, simply adjust the .font.size property of each cell.

As an additional thaught: given the crappy layout of excel-pasted tables and the slowness of the table object when you modify it it would probably be faster to CREATE a powerpoint table to your liking and then paste the values from excel into the new table. Simply iterate over each cell and assign a value to the .text property.
If you can use the default powerpoint styles there is a possibility to set each table to a style programmatically, search for the.style property of the table object.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I did.
`for (int k = startmultiplicator; k <= pptshape.Table.Rows.Count; k++)
{for (int l = 1; l <= pptshape.Table.Columns.Count; l++)
{
   objTable.Cell(incrementer, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = pptshape.Table.Cell(k, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                                        objTable.Cell(incrementer, l).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = fontsize;
                                    }`
                                    incrementer++;
                                }